Proving the convergence of an alternating sequence
Prove that the series given below is convergent.$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}$$
The original problem was to investigate the convergence of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}x^n$. I used Cauchy's root test to conclude that the series is convergent when $|x|<1$ and divergent when $|x|>1$, for $x=1$ we use the limit comparison test with the harmonic series to get that the series is divergent but when $x=-1$ the series becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}$$ Now the above series is an alternating series and I am not able to prove whether it is convergent or divergent, although according to the answer it is convergent.
P.S. Thanks for any help

$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}=\frac1n\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n$

If $n\in\Bbb N$, then$$\frac{\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+2}}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}}=\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+2}}\cdot\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}=\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}<1.$$Therefore, the sequence $\left(\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing. So, by the alternating series test, and since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=0,$$your series converges.

Thanks for your help

I'm glad I could help.

A very useful convergence criteria for alternating series is the Leibniz criterion, which reads as follows:
TH. Let $\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nx_n$ be an alternating series. Then, if both the conditions:

$(|x_n|)_{n\geq 0}$ is decreasing,

$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$,


are satisfied, then the alternating series $\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nx_n$ is convergent.

Thanks for your help

With pleasure !
